# How to treat this error?(stack smashing deteced Aborted(core dumped) )

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

void TreatFile(int first, int last)
{
    int fhist, fdata;
    char fdname[8];
    int hisSum[256]= {0};
    unsigned char data_cont;
    int i, j ,exec_struct;
    struct timeval tp1, tp2;
    double tvalue, t_mean,t_devi;
    double exec_t[128];
    double t_sum = 0;
    double t_variance = 0;

    for(i=first; i<=last; i++)
    {
        sprintf(fdname,"data%d.bin", i);
        exec_struct = gettimeofday(&tp1, NULL);

        fhist=open("histogram.bin", O_RDONLY);

        for(j=0; j<256; j++)
            read(fhist, hisSum+j, 1);

        close(fhist);

        fdata=open(fdname, O_RDONLY);

        for(j=0; j<256*256; j++)
        {
            read(fdata,&data_cont,1);
            hisSum[data_cont]++;
        }

        close(fdata);

        fhist=open("histogram.bin", O_WRONLY);

        for(j=0; j<256; j++)
            write(fhist, hisSum+j, 4);

        close(fhist);

        exec_struct = gettimeofday(&tp2, NULL);
        tvalue = (tp2.tv_sec - tp1.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + (tp2.tv_usec - tp1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;

        printf("[%d]th data execution time : %f\n",i,tvalue);

        exec_t[i] = tvalue;
        t_sum += tvalue;

    }

    t_mean = t_sum/(last-first+1);

    for(i=0; i<(last-first+1); i++)
        t_variance += pow(t_mean-exec_t[i],2.0);

    t_devi = sqrt(t_variance/(double) (last-first+1));

    printf("Total execution time is %lf\n", t_sum);
    printf("Mean of execution time is %lf\n", t_mean);
    printf("Standard diviation is %lf\n", t_devi);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int first, last;

    first = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(first);
    last = atoi(argv[2]);
    assert(last);
    TreatFile(first, last);

    return 0;
}
```

1. first make 128 file! with `dd if=/dev/random of=data$i bs=64K count=1`
2. and make histogram.bin with

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=histogram.bin bs=4 count=256
   ```

Hello! Here is my code!

The source code's result makes stack smashing error!

I think this code -`read(fdata,&data_cont,1);`- has some problem(stack overflow).

But I can't get a handle on replacing it with appropriate expression.

Would you please help me?

Comment: The string `"data%d.bin"` will be at *least* ***10*** characters (don't forget the terminator!). And you try to fit it into an array of 8 characters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `read` except you not checking the return value. It reads one byte into the address of an unsigned char. It's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is likely to be this line

```
sprintf(fdname,"data%d.bin", i);
```

If `i` is between 0 and 9, the line above attempts to fill the buffer with 10 characters e.g. `data0.bin\0`. If `i` is any larger, the string is even longer. Unfortuantely, you have only defined `fdName` to be eight bytes long.

There are some other issues.

```
for(j=0;j<256*256;j++)
{
    read(fdata,&data_cont,1);
    hisSum[data_cont]++;
}
```

You use `data_cont` uninitialsed if the `read` fails to read any bytes. Always check the return value of IO functions.

In this code

```
for(j=0;j<256;j++)
    write(fhist, hisSum+j, 4);
```

If `j` is greater than 252, you read beyond the end of `hisSum`.

In `main` you don't check to make sure `argc` is at least 3.

Also, you leak the `fhist` read file descriptor when you overwrite it with the write file descriptor. without closing it first.